# Sudoku Solver - uses DFS and Constraint Propagation

Tags: java, sudoku

Disclaimer: My code is translated from Peter Norvig's [Python code](http://norvig.com/sudoku.html).

This simple code uses only two techniques: [Constraint Satisfaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction) and [Depth-First-Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search). Backtracking is not implemented.

Here's the code:

### Board.java

```
package core;

import java.util.*;

import static core.Constants.*;

/**
 * This class represents a particular Board "state", with immutable mappings.
 * These can be considered as nodes in the search tree without any links. The
 * creation of Nodes is done separately in Main.java, during search.
 *
 * @author Subhomoy Haldar
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class Board {

    /**
     * This immutable map stores the relations between the squares and the
     * possible values.
     */
    private final Map<String, String> candidateMap;

    /**
     * Creates a new Board with the given trusted map. Used internally by Main.
     *
     * @param trustedCandidateMap The trusted map to be used.
     */
    protected Board(final Map<String, String> trustedCandidateMap) {
        candidateMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(trustedCandidateMap);
    }

    /**
     * It is used to create a new Board from a pre-existing one with just one
     * change to be effected.
     *
     * @param previous     The previous state/node in the tree.
     * @param square       The square to manipulate.
     * @param trustedValue The value to assign to the square.
     */
    protected Board(final Board previous, String square, String trustedValue) {
        Map<String, String> temporaryMap
                = new LinkedHashMap<>(previous.candidateMap);
        temporaryMap.put(square, trustedValue);
        candidateMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(temporaryMap);
    }

    /**
     * Performs constraint propagation. It is basically removing the
     * possibilities based on marked squares. Those with only one possible
     * candidate end up being marked.
     *
     * @return The result of applying constraint propagation.
     */
    public Board propagate() {
        int eliminations = 0;
        Map<String, String> cMap = new LinkedHashMap<>(this.candidateMap);
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : cMap.entrySet()) {
            String square = entry.getKey();
            String candidates = entry.getValue();
            // check for wrong solution
            if (candidates.isEmpty()) {
                return null;
            }
            // check for finalised
            if (candidates.length() == 1) {
                for (String peer : PEERS.get(square)) {
                    String peerValues = cMap.get(peer);
                    if (peerValues.length() > 1 &&
                            peerValues.contains(candidates)) {
                        eliminations++;
                        peerValues = peerValues.replace(candidates, "");
                        cMap.put(peer, peerValues);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return eliminations == 0 ? this : new Board(cMap);
    }

    /**
     * Returns <code>true</code> if every square is marked and has only one
     * candidate.
     *
     * @return <code>true</code> if every square is marked and has only one
     * candidate.
     */
    public boolean isSolved() {
        for (String values : candidateMap.values()) {
            if (values.length() > 1) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Returns <code>true</code> if there is any repetition in any of the units.
     *
     * @return <code>true</code> if there is any repetition in any of the units.
     */
    public boolean isWrong() {
        for (List<String> unit : UNITS) {
            for (char number : CANDIDATES.toCharArray()) {
                int count = 0;
                for (String square : unit) {
                    String candidates = candidateMap.get(square);
                    if (candidates.length() == 1 &&
                            candidates.charAt(0) == number)
                        count++;
                }
                if (count > 1) return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the square with the minimum number of candidates. This is
     * useful in search to reduce the rate of choosing the wrong branch.
     *
     * @return The square with the minimum number of candidates.
     */
    public Map.Entry<String, String> minimumCandidatePair() {
        Map.Entry<String, String> minimum = null;
        int number = SIZE + 1;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : candidateMap.entrySet()) {
            String candidates = entry.getValue();
            if (number > candidates.length() && candidates.length() > 1) {
                number = candidates.length();
                minimum = entry;
            }
        }
        return minimum;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the current Board state as a String. The unmarked squared are
     * represented by a '.'.
     *
     * @return The current Board state as a String.
     */
    public String toString() {
        StringJoiner fullJoiner = new StringJoiner(
                "\n",
                "\n+-----------------------+\n",
                "\n+-----------------------+\n");
        StringJoiner lineJoiner = new StringJoiner(" ", "| ", " |");
        int i = 1, j = 1;
        for (String value : candidateMap.values()) {
            lineJoiner.add(value.length() == 1 ? value : ".");
            if (i % SIZE == 0) {
                fullJoiner.add(lineJoiner.toString());
                lineJoiner = new StringJoiner(" ", "| ", " |");
                if (j % UNIT == 0 && j != SIZE) {
                    fullJoiner.add("|-------+-------+-------|");
                }
                j++;
            } else if (i % UNIT == 0) {
                lineJoiner.add("|");
            }
            i++;
        }
        return fullJoiner.toString();
    }
}
```

### Constants.java

```
package core;

    import java.util.*;

    /**
     * This class generates and stores constants that will be used frequently
     * throughout the project.
     *
     * @author Subhomoy Haldar
     * @version 1.0
     */
    public class Constants {
        /**
         * The side of the smaller square unit.
         */
        public static final int UNIT = 3;
        /**
         * The number of squares in one unit.
         */
        public static final int SIZE = UNIT * UNIT;
        /**
         * The total number of squares in the game.
         */
        public static final int NUMBER_OF_SQUARES = SIZE * SIZE;
        /**
         * The String containing all the possible candidates.
         */
        public static final String CANDIDATES;
        /**
         * The list of all the squares in the game.
         */
        public static final List<String> SQUARES;
        /**
         * The list of all units (rows, columns, squares) in the game.
         */
        public static final List<List<String>> UNITS;
        /**
         * The map between every square and its set of peers.
         */
        public static final Map<String, Set<String>> PEERS;

        /**
         * The maximum number of times the Generator will run the shuffle loop.
         */
        protected static final int MAX_SHUFFLE = 20;

        static {
            // All the possibilities linearly stored in this String
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(SIZE);
            for (int i = 1; i <= SIZE; i++) {
                builder.append(i);
            }
            CANDIDATES = builder.toString();

            // Generate the square labels
            List<String> squareList = new ArrayList<>(NUMBER_OF_SQUARES);
            char row = 'A';
            char col;
            for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++, row++) {
                col = '1';
                for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++, col++) {
                    String square = "" + row + col;
                    squareList.add(square);
                }
            }
            SQUARES = Collections.unmodifiableList(squareList);

            // Generate the units
            List<List<String>> temporaryLists = new ArrayList<>(SIZE * 3);
            // First, the rows
            row = 'A';
            for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++, row++) {
                List<String> squares = new ArrayList<>(SIZE);
                col = '1';
                for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++, col++) {
                    squares.add("" + row + col);
                }
                temporaryLists.add(squares);
            }
            // Second, the columns
            col = '1';
            for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++, col++) {
                row = 'A';
                List<String> squares = new ArrayList<>(SIZE);
                for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++, row++) {
                    squares.add("" + row + col);
                }
                temporaryLists.add(squares);
            }
            // Third, the squares
            int xOffset = 0;
            int yOffset = 0;
            while (xOffset < UNIT && yOffset < UNIT) {
                List<String> squares = new ArrayList<>(SIZE);
                for (int i = 0; i < UNIT; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < UNIT; j++) {
                        col = (char) ('1' + xOffset * UNIT + j);
                        row = (char) ('A' + yOffset * UNIT + i);
                        squares.add("" + row + col);
                    }
                }
                temporaryLists.add(squares);
                xOffset++;
                if (xOffset == UNIT) {
                    xOffset = 0;
                    yOffset++;
                }
            }
            UNITS = Collections.unmodifiableList(temporaryLists);

            // The peers for each square
            Map<String, Set<String>> peerMap = new HashMap<>(NUMBER_OF_SQUARES);
            for (String square : SQUARES) {
                Set<String> peers = new HashSet<>(SIZE * 3 + 2 * (SIZE - UNIT));
                UNITS.stream()
                        .filter(unit -> unit.contains(square))
                        .forEach(peers::addAll);
                peers.remove(square);
                peerMap.put(square, peers);
            }
            PEERS = Collections.unmodifiableMap(peerMap);
        }
    }
```

### Parser.java

```
package core;

import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import static core.Constants.*;

/**
 * Handles the parsing of various formats and produces a Board.
 *
 * @author Subhomoy Haldar
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class Parser {

    /**
     * Parses a given String and tries to generate a Board with the required
     * state and mappings.
     * <p>
     * This parser will only accept numbers 1 through 9 (or Constants#SIZE)
     * and map them to their respective squares. '0' and '.' represent blank
     * squares. <b>All other characters are ignored.</b>
     *
     * @param input The input String to parse.
     * @return The corresponding Board.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException If the input is invalid.
     */
    public static Board parse(String input) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        Map<String, String> state = new LinkedHashMap<>(NUMBER_OF_SQUARES);
        int i = 0;
        for (String square : SQUARES) {
            try {
                char c;
                do {
                    c = input.charAt(i++);
                } while (!(CANDIDATES.indexOf(c) > -1 || c == '0' || c == '.'));
                state.put(square, CANDIDATES.indexOf(c) > -1
                        ? String.valueOf(c)
                        : CANDIDATES);
            } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException ignore) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input cannot be parsed.");
            }
        }
        return new Board(state);
    }

    /**
     * Parses the given trusted array. It is used internally to generate the
     * initial Board randomly.
     *
     * @param trustedArray The trusted array to parse.
     * @return The corresponding Board.
     */
    protected static Board parse(int[][] trustedArray) {
        Map<String, String> state = new LinkedHashMap<>(NUMBER_OF_SQUARES);
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        for (String square : SQUARES) {
            char c = (char) ('0' + trustedArray[i][j++]);
            state.put(square, CANDIDATES.indexOf(c) > -1
                    ? String.valueOf(c)
                    : CANDIDATES
            );
            if (j == SIZE) {
                j = 0;
                i++;
            }
        }
        return new Board(state);
    }
}
```

### Main.java

```
package core;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * The main class that handles search and constraint propagation methods. It
 * serves as the entry-point.
 *
 * @author Subhomoy Haldar
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class Main {

    /**
     * A handy template for reference.
     */
    private static final String BLANK = "" +
            "+-----------------------+\n" +
            "| . . . | . . . | . . . |\n" +
            "| . . . | . . . | . . . |\n" +
            "| . . . | . . . | . . . |\n" +
            "|-------+-------+-------|\n" +
            "| . . . | . . . | . . . |\n" +
            "| . . . | . . . | . . . |\n" +
            "| . . . | . . . | . . . |\n" +
            "|-------+-------+-------|\n" +
            "| . . . | . . . | . . . |\n" +
            "| . . . | . . . | . . . |\n" +
            "| . . . | . . . | . . . |\n" +
            "+-----------------------+";


    /**
     * The entry point for the program. Currently it does not accept any input.
     * It won't be difficult to do that. I encourage everyone to tinker with
     * the code.
     *
     * @param args The command-line arguments (which are ignored)
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // The following is supposed to be the world's "hardest" Sudoku puzzle.
        Board board = Parser.parse("" +
                "+-----------------------+\n" +
                "| 8 . . | . . . | . . . |\n" +
                "| . . 3 | 6 . . | . . . |\n" +
                "| . 7 . | . 9 . | 2 . . |\n" +
                "|-------+-------+-------|\n" +
                "| . 5 . | . . 7 | . . . |\n" +
                "| . . . | . 4 5 | 7 . . |\n" +
                "| . . . | 1 . . | . 3 . |\n" +
                "|-------+-------+-------|\n" +
                "| . . 1 | . . . | . 6 8 |\n" +
                "| . . 8 | 5 . . | . 1 . |\n" +
                "| . 9 . | . . . | 4 . . |\n" +
                "+-----------------------+"
        );
        //Board board = Parser.parse(Generator.generateSolved());
        System.out.println(board);
        List<Board> solutions = new ArrayList<>();
        search(board, solutions);
        if (solutions.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No solution found. Input is invalid.");
        } else if (solutions.size() == 1) {
            System.out.println(solutions.get(0));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid Sudoku : multiple solutions.");
            System.out.println("Number of solutions = " + solutions.size());
            System.out.println("The solutions are ... ");
            System.out.println(solutions);

        }
    }

    /**
     * Carries on constraint propagation till no further values can be
     * eliminated.
     *
     * @param board The starting point for propagation.
     * @return The end result of propagation.
     */
    private static Board propagateTillPossible(Board board) {
        while (true) {
            Board newBoard = board.propagate();
            if (newBoard == null || newBoard == board) return newBoard;
            board = newBoard;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Performs a DFS (Depth-First-Search) of the possible states. Eliminates
     * as many state possibilities as possible using constraint propagation.
     *
     * @param board The state to work with.
     */
    private static void search(Board board, List<Board> solutions) {
        // The board provided is faulty
        if (board == null || board.isWrong())
            return;

        // Solution obtained
        if (board.isSolved()) {
            solutions.add(board);
            return;
        }

        // Proceeding with the square with minimum candidates helps to reduce
        // the chance of failure. For example, if we proceed with 7 (say)
        // possibilities, we may fail 6 out of 7 times. However, if we
        // proceed with 2 (say), we may fail at most half of the time.
        Map.Entry<String, String> pair = board.minimumCandidatePair();

        // Try out every possibility and see how far (or deep into the search
        // space) we can go. At least one branch is guaranteed to yield a
        // solution.
        for (char c : pair.getValue().toCharArray()) {
            String value = String.valueOf(c);

            Board next = new Board(board, pair.getKey(), value);
            next = propagateTillPossible(next);
            search(next, solutions);

        }
    }

}
```

I'm not posting [Generator.java](https://github.com/Subh0m0y/Sudoku/blob/master/src/core/Generator.java) because it's still unfinished.

Comments/criticism welcome on any aspect.

Comment: Has your question been resolved? If so, please consider accepting an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Use of `String`

I do not like the use of `String` for representing board position and grid candidates. For board positions I think you would have been better to just use grid index \$0\le i\lt 9^2\$. Not only is this more effective because you don't have to do a lot of string comparisons and manipulation, and you don't have to compute the string hash for every lookup in the `candidateMap`, but it is also more clear to read.

For the candidates for a given position I think that a `Set<Integer>` would be better. Again it communicates the intent better and `HashSet` allows faster, \$\mathcal{O}\left(1\right)\$ lookup compared to `String.contains` which is \$\mathcal{O}\left(n\right)\$.

I think overall using `Map<Integer, Set<Integer>>` for `candidateMap` would be much cleaner and easier to read.

## Single Responsibility Principle

The `propagate()` function checks for wrong solutions and performs constraint propagation. Because you have `isWrong()` which you are checking in the DFS then then I don't think that `propagate()` needs to, or even should check for wrong solutions.

## Constants

I think that some of the constants, `SQUARES`, `UNITS`, `PEERS` are a bit hard to understand at a glance. I think mainly this is due to the use of `String` everywhere. And I think that they subtract from readability.

For example look at the `UNITS` constant, it is used at exactly one place, in `isWrong()`. When reading `isWrong()` I have to look at both the constants and the code and figure out how they relate. For me I would have liked to just read the complete logic in `isWrong()` without flicking back and forth between constants and board. Same thing goes for `PEERS` and propagate.

With that in mind I'm not going to review `Constants.java` further, even though I think the name is spectacularly bad, at least name it `SudokuConstants` same thing with `Parser` and `Board`.

## Parser

I don't find the parser particularly interesting and the comments I have already given about use of `String` would make any review here moot I think.

## PropagateTillPossible

The name is a bit hard to understand, possible what? Reading the code I see that it repeatedly propagates until either the solution is deemed invalid or there is no change in the board. To be honest I think that this should be done by `Board.Propagate()` simply because I can't think of a case where you wouldn't want to propagate all the way.

## DFS with Back-Tracking

The depth first search that you have implemented is using back-tracking. The conceptual implementation is this:

```
dfs(node, solutions)
    if(reject(node)) (#3)
        return
    if(accept(node))
        solutions.add(node)

    child = first(node) (#1)
    while(child != nil)
        dfs(child)
        child = next(child) (#2)
    end
end
```

where `reject(node)` returns true only if the node can never become a solution (i.e. `Board.isWrong()`). And accept returns true only if the node is a valid solution (i.e. `Board.isSolved()`). The function `first` return the first child of `node` in the search tree in your case this is `minimumCandidatePair()` and taking the first candidate. The function `next` returns the next sibling of `child` in the search tree, in your case it is equivalent to taking the next candidate grid value from the `minimumCandidatePair()`.